# spamassassin - blacklist not working

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, ubuntu-server, spamassassin

On my ubuntu-server (14.04 LTS) I installed postfix, dovecot, amavis, clamav and spamassassin. I want to define global rules to blacklist mail-addresses.

Therefore in the /etc/spamassassin/local.cf file I wrote...

```
blacklist_from *@andre-hohmann.net
```

...and I restartet amavis and spamassassin. But a testmail from info@andre-hohmann.net is getting through with "X-Spam-Flag: NO".

If I send another testmail with "XJS*C4JDBQADN1.NSBN3*2IDNEN*GTUBE-STANDARD-ANTI-UBE-TEST-EMAIL*C.34X" in the mailtext, the X-Spam_Flag" is set to YES.

In my /etc/postfix/main.cf I added...

```
# Use amavis for virus and spam scanning
content_filter = amavis:[127.0.0.1]:10024
```

...and at the end of my /etc/postfix/master.cf the following:

```
# The next two entries integrate with Amavis for anti-virus/spam checks.
amavis      unix    -       -       -       -       3       smtp
  -o smtp_data_done_timeout=1200
  -o smtp_send_xforward_command=yes
  -o disable_dns_lookups=yes
  -o max_use=20
#  -o smtp_tls_security_level=none
127.0.0.1:10025 inet    n       -       -       -       -       smtpd
  -o content_filter=
  -o local_recipient_maps=
  -o relay_recipient_maps=
  -o smtpd_restriction_classes=
  -o smtpd_delay_reject=no
  -o smtpd_client_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_helo_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_sender_restrictions=
  -o smtpd_recipient_restrictions=permit_mynetworks,reject
  -o smtpd_data_restrictions=reject_unauth_pipelining
  -o smtpd_end_of_data_restrictions=
  -o mynetworks=127.0.0.0/8
  -o smtpd_error_sleep_time=0
  -o smtpd_soft_error_limit=1001
  -o smtpd_hard_error_limit=1000
  -o smtpd_client_connection_count_limit=0
  -o smtpd_client_connection_rate_limit=0
  -o receive_override_options=no_header_body_checks,no_unknown_recipient_checks
```

Does anybody know, why my blacklist-entry isn't considered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reinstalling spamassassin and restarting only amavis it works now.